# How to increase the nth-child values during the run time?

Tags: robotframework

For your reference:
   I need to increase the nth-child values upto 'n' numbers during the run time.

```
div.col:nth-child**(1)** > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div

div.col:nth-child**(2)** > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div

div.col:nth-child**(3)** > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? Please look at [ask] for more details of the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Use For loop to achieve, I had added ${num} variable inside the nth-child

```
:FOR    ${num}  IN RANGE    0   5
\    Log    div.col:nth-child(${num}) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div
```

you will get ouput like this

```
  div.col:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div
 div.col:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div
 div.col:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div
 div.col:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div
```